# LINQ select multiple columns as separate array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I have table 4 columns.

```
JobId    StateId    Salary       Expense
1           1        35,000      31,000
1           1        33,000      25,000
1           2        28,000      26,000
2           2         7,000      16,000
2           2         6,000      20,000
2           1         9,000      22,000
2           1        15,000      29,000
```

By using LINQ in C#, i want to group by JobId and StateId combination.For each combination i want an array of Salary and array of Expense.

I can get one column as a array by for each combination, by using this

```
(from r in myTable.AsEnumerable()
       group r by new {
            jobId = r.Field<int>("JobId"),
            stateId = r.Field<int>("StateId")
        }).ToDictionary(
        l => Tuple.Create(l.Key.jobId, l.Key.stateId),
        l=> (from i in l select i.Field<double>("Salary")).AsEnumerable()
  );
```

How can i have Salary and Expense in two array for each group??

My goal is to find average Salary and average Expense for each combination and do some other operation. Or at least tell me how can select multiple columns as separate array.

Note: I don't want collection of anonymous objects for each combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select two different columns as collections in your query you can do this:

```
var result = 
    (from r in myTable.AsEnumerable()
     group r by new 
     {
         jobId = r.Field<int>("JobId"),
         stateId = r.Field<int>("StateId")
     } into g
     select new 
     {
         g.Key,
         Salaries = g.Select(x => x.Field<double>("Salary")),
         Expenses = g.Select(x => x.Field<double>("Expense"))
     })
    .ToDictionary(
        l => Tuple.Create(l.Key.jobId, l.Key.stateId),
        l => new { l.Salaries, l.Expenses }
    );
```

Then you can compute the averages fairly easily:

```
var averageSalary = result[...].Salaries.Average();
var averageExpense = result[...].Expenses.Average();
```

But if all you really need is the averages, this will work:

```
var result = 
    (from r in myTable.AsEnumerable()
     group r by new 
     {
         jobId = r.Field<int>("JobId"),
         stateId = r.Field<int>("StateId")
     } into g
     select new 
     {
         g.Key,
         AverageSalary = g.Average(x => x.Field<double>("Salary")),
         AverageExpense = g.Average(x => x.Field<double>("Expense"))
     })
    .ToDictionary(
        l => Tuple.Create(l.Key.jobId, l.Key.stateId),
        l => new { l.AverageSalary, l.AverageExpense }
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to do some extra work besides average. In the later process i want to pick the array of expense / salary for a particular combination and do some processing

Comment: @KhanSharp in which case you can just use my first code sample. I've included a bit more information for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use LINQ for this kind of statement.  If you need to count the groupings and the compute some sort of average salary/expense you could try a list:

```
List<myType> myList = new List<myType>();

//add stuff to myList

List<myType> JobID1 = new List<myType();
List<myType> JobID2 = new List<myType();

foreach(var item in myList)
{
    if(item.JobID == 1)
        JobID1.add(item);
    if(item.JobID == 2)
        JobID2.add(item);
}

int avgSalOne;

foreach(var item in JobID1)
{
    avgSalOne += item.Salary;
}

avgSalOne = avgSaleOne / JobID2.Count;

//Note that you get Job Id 2 average salary the same way, and also the Expense by changing item. Salary to item.Expense
```

Comment: There are going to be a lot of `IF statements` if he starts doing combinations of `JobID` with `StateID`.

Comment: I have a really large array and i want to take benefit of deferred execution of LINQ as well as parallel execution

Comment: @KhanSharp youre not gonna have parallel execution here